# Am I missing anything? Solving Equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to know what $ a^4+b^4+c^4 $ would be when

$ a+b+c=1, a^2+b^2+c^2=2, a^3+b^3+c^3=3. $

I tried

```
Solve[{a + b + c == 1, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 2, 
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 == 3}, {a, b, c}]

a^4 + b^4 + c^4 /. {a -> ... }
```

I copied and pasted one instance from the result of `Solve[]` into `{a -> ...}`

The solution and the result of `Simplify[]` of it was not quite what I expected.

So as a test, I tried `a+b+c /. {a -> ...}`

Still it was strange, it didn't come up with 1 which is obvious correct answer.

So am I missing anything here?

Is there any better way?

Comment: As a quick check, try `sol=Solve[...]` and then `1. (a + b + c) /. sol`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solve your equations with respect to another variable `d == a^4 + b^4 + c^4` eliminating given ones

```
Solve[{ a + b + c == 1,       a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 2, 
        a^3 + b^3 + c^3 == 3, a^4 + b^4 + c^4 == d},  {d}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{d -> 25/6}}
> ```

This tutorial will be helpful [Eliminating Variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html).

**Edit**

For the sake of completeness we add another methods of dealing with the problem. Let's point out even simpler way than the first one, just add assumptions to `Simplify`:

```
Simplify[ a^4 + b^4 + c^4, {a + b + c == 1, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 2, a^3 + b^3 + c^3 == 3}]
```

> ```
> 25/6
> ```

Of course we can use `FullSimplify` as well. In this case, `Simplify` works nicely, but the first method is stronger and should work in more general cases.

`SymmetricReduction` is more appropriate when we would like to get  symbolic results, i.e. here we would like to express `a^4 + b^4 + c^4` in terms of these polynomials: {`a + b + c, a^2 + b^2 + c^2, a^3 + b^3 + c^3`}

First we need to get rid of unknown symmetric polynomials (we know only `a + b + c`):

```
 SymmetricPolynomial[#, {a, b, c}] & /@ Range[3]
```

> ```
> {a + b + c, a b + a c + b c, a b c}
> ```

form the last reduction using the previous ones:

```
First @ SymmetricReduction[ a^# + b^# + c^#, {a, b, c}] & /@ Range[4] // Column
```

> ```
> a + b + c
>
> (a + b + c)^2 - 2 (a b + a c + b c)
>
> 3 a b c + (a + b + c)^3 - 3 (a + b + c) (a b + a c + b c) 
>
> 4 a b c (a + b + c) + (a + b + c)^4 - 4 (a + b + c)^2 (a b + a c + b c)
> + 2 (a b + a c + b c)^2
> ```

Now we have `a^4 + b^4 + c^4` expressed in terms of given polynomials:

```
str = 
First[ SymmetricReduction[ a^4 + b^4 + c^4, {a, b, c}]] //. {
  (a b + a c + b c) -> 1/2 (a + b + c)^2 - 1/2 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2),
  (a b c) -> 1/3 (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) - 1/3 (a + b + c)^3 + (a + b + c) (a b + a c + b c)}
```

> ```
>  (a + b + c)^4 - 4 (a + b + c)^2 (1/2 (a + b + c)^2 + 1/2 (-a^2 - b^2 - c^2))
>  + 2 (1/2(a + b + c)^2 + 1/2(-a^2 - b^2 - c^2))^2 + 4(a + b + c) (-(1/3)(a + b + c)^3
>  + 1/3 (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + (a + b + c) (1/2 (a + b + c)^2 + 1/2 (-a^2 - b^2 - c^2)))
> ```

of course

```
Simplify @ %
```

> ```
> a^4 + b^4 + c^4
> ```

and finally:

```
str /. {a + b + c -> 1, (-a^2 - b^2 - c^2) -> -2, (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) -> 3}
```

> ```
> 25/6
> ```

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the route using elementary symmetric functions has been neglected, so I'll discuss this. Recall that by Newton-Girard, one can always express power sums in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials. *Mathematica* has the function `SymmetricReduction[]` that allows you to express power sums in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials; now, when given values for the power sums, one can obtain the values for the corresponding elementary symmetric polynomials, and then use these to evaluate higher-order power sums. In particular, you can do the following:

```
First @ SymmetricReduction[a^4 + b^4 + c^4, {a, b, c}, C /@ Range[3]] /. 
     First @ Solve[Table[
           First[SymmetricReduction[a^k + b^k + c^k, {a, b, c},C /@ Range[3]]] == k,
                         {k, 3}], C /@ Range[3]]
```

which gives the result $25/6$.

Comment: Interesting: `SymmetricReduction` eliminates the need for `FullSimplify` and is about 100 times faster on my machine. Not a "simple" presentation, but effective.

Comment: I consider it "simple" in the sense that the elementary symmetric polynomials are "nicer" to handle than power sums. Of course, looking at how this answer has been received, the mathematical advantages are not fully appreciated by most...

Comment: @J.M. Exactly, why use mathematics if you have Mathematica:)?

Comment: @Ajasja, let the computer do the thinking instead of your brain, why not... :)

Comment: Even in the era of super fast computing, we are still in need of faster algorithms and always will be... :)

Comment: @KHKim, yes, but as you see, the lazy solution is preferred by more people, at least in this case.

Comment: @J.M. Oh I might as well take your answer if I could. Thank you for the excellent answer. But to my shame, I can't understand it! I better look at it later. And I think recognizing a symmetric expression would be a piece of cake for Mathematica, so I wonder why the developers couldn't fit it in so that we should ponder on it and express it explicit!

Comment: @KHKim, probably because recognizing the symmetry programmatically would be more trouble than it's worth, and one can instead choose to use a slower, but more general algorithm. Again: computers do not have to think.

Comment: @KHKim, I'm not normally nice, but I'll make an exception for you today: [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial); [Newton-Girard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities). Read up, and (hopefully) enjoy.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your exception and exceptional niceness. :)

Comment: @J.M. I like your answer (+1), nonetheless your solution has been lazy too, so I've just made mine a bit more elaborated.

Comment: @Artes, too bad I cannot upvote again, but I do notice you chose not to use the third argument of `SymmetricReduction[]`... ;) BTW, by "lazy", I meant one just chucks the equations to be solved into `Solve[]`; that certainly does not need much thought, but is convenient when the operator is not mathematically sophisticated.

Answer (score 6):

[Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26148/52) has the obvious answer, but there are a couple of other methods that work.

```
a = Solve[{a + b + c == 1, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 2, a^3 + b^3 + c^3 == 3}, {a, b, c}]
```

You can get the numerical equivalent:

```
a^4 + b^4 + c^4 /. a // N
(*
 {4.16667 - 1.28618*10^-15 I, 4.16667 - 2.86492*10^-16 I, 
  4.16667 + 1.28618*10^-15 I, 4.16667 + 2.86492*10^-16 I, 
  4.16667 + 0. I, 4.16667 + 0. I
 }
*)
```

where it is obvious that the imaginary parts are due to numerical error, and can be taken care of using `Chop`. Perhaps the other most obvious method is to use `Simplify`, but it does not give anything that is helpful. So, next in line is its big brother `FullSimplify`:

```
b = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 /. a // FullSimplify
(*
 {25/6, 25/6, 25/6, 25/6, 25/6, 25/6}
*)
```

For sanity sake,

```
N @ b
(*
 {4.16667, 4.16667, 4.16667, 4.16667, 4.16667, 4.16667}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Solve[{a + b + c == 1, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 2, a^3 + b^3 + c^3 == 3, 
  a^4 + b^4 + c^4 == d}, d, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]

(*
{{d -> ConditionalExpression[25/6, 
    a + b + c == 1 && -b + b^2 - c + b c + c^2 == 1/ 2 && -c - 2 c^2 + 2 c^3 == 1/3]}}
*)

Reduce[{a + b + c == 1, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 2, a^3 + b^3 + c^3 == 3, 
  a^4 + b^4 + c^4 == d}]

(*
 d == 25/6 && (c == Root[-1 - 3 #1 - 6 #1^2 + 6 #1^3 &, 1] || 
   c == Root[-1 - 3 #1 - 6 #1^2 + 6 #1^3 &, 2] || 
   c == Root[-1 - 3 #1 - 6 #1^2 + 6 #1^3 &, 3]) && (b == 
    1/2 (1 - c - Sqrt[3 + 2 c - 3 c^2]) || 
   b == 1/2 (1 - c + Sqrt[3 + 2 c - 3 c^2])) && a == 1 - b - c
*)
```