# How to replace every possible $A+B$ and $AB$ in expansion of $(A+B)^{10}-A^{10}-B^{10}$ with $x$ and $y$, respectively?

Tags: replacement, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to replace every possible $A+B$ and $AB$ in expansion of $(A+B)^{10}-A^{10}-B^{10}$ with
$x$ and $y$, respectively.  How to do it with the simplest code in *Mathematica*?

For example,

\begin{align*}
(A+B)^3-A^3-B^3 &= 3AB(A+B)\\
&= 3xy
\end{align*}

In other words, having $A+B=x$ and $AB=y$, how do I express $(A+B)^{10}-A^{10}-B^{10}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

### Bonus question

Rather than creating a new question for it, I think I should ask here. If I want to find $a^{10}+b^{10}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, why does

```
Simplify[(a + b)^10 - Expand[(a + b)^10 - a^10 - b^10],a b == x && a + b == y]
```

not produce the expected result?

Comment: Related: [Am I missing anything? Solving Equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26147/am-i-missing-anything-solving-equations)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `GroebnerBasis`:

```
eq = (a + b)^10 - a^10 - b^10;
eqXY = GroebnerBasis[{eq, a + b - x, a b - y}, {x, y}, {a, b}];

(*out*){10 x^8 y - 35 x^6 y^2 + 50 x^4 y^3 - 25 x^2 y^4 + 2 y^5}
```

Check:

```
First@Expand[eqXY /. x -> (a + b) /. y -> a b] === Expand[eq]
(*out*)True
```

**--EDIT--**

Following @DanielLichtblau's suggestion, it's better to do this in two steps: first find a Groebner basis (of the polynomials corresponding to the transformation equations) and then reduce your polynomial in terms of the basis to account for the case where not all variables get eliminated. I trust he knows what he's talking about having written parts of the function :). So,

```
With[{
   vars = {a, b},
   relations = {a + b - x, a b - y},
   poly = (a + b)^10 - a^10 - b^10},
  PolynomialReduce[poly, GroebnerBasis[relations, vars], 
   vars]] // Last
(*out*){10 x^8 y - 35 x^6 y^2 + 50 x^4 y^3 - 25 x^2 y^4 + 2 y^5}
```

is safer. In fact, I realised your question is answered by one of the examples in the "Applications" section of the [documentation for `PolynomialReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolynomialReduce.html)

Comment: If I want to find $a^{10}+b^{10}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, why does `Simplify[(a + b)^10 - Expand[(a + b)^10 - a^10 - b^10], 
 a b == x && a + b == y]` not produce the expected result?

Comment: `GroebnerBasis[{a^10 + b^10, a + b - x, a b - y}, {x, y}, {a, b}]` produces the expected result.

Comment: This is reasonable (I upvoted..) I'd recommend separating into a GB followed by polynomial reduction though. `In[607]:= vars = {a, b, x, y};

In[608]:= 
PolynomialReduce[(a + b)^3 - (a^3 + b^3), 
  GroebnerBasis[{a + b - x, a*b - y}, vars], vars][[2]]

Out[608]= 3 x y` Reason being that the replacement will not in general result in certain variables being eliminated, so a GB alone might not suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I edited to match the example in the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Simplify` and give your replacements as assumptions:

```
Simplify[(a + b)^3 - a^3 - b^3, a + b == x && a b == y]
(* 3 x y *)

(* For higher n seems like you have to Expand first *)
Simplify[(a + b)^10 - a^10 - b^10 // Expand, a + b == x && a b == y]
(* y (10 x^8 - 35 x^6 y + 50 x^4 y^2 - 25 x^2 y^3 + 2 y^4) *)

(* Or alternatively use a custom ComplexityFunction *)
Simplify[
 (a + b)^n - a^n - b^n, a + b == x && a b == y,
 ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, a | b, Infinity] &)] // Simplify
```

Comment: If I want to find $a^{10}+b^{10}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, why does `Simplify[(a + b)^10 - Expand[(a + b)^10 - a^10 - b^10], 
 a b == x && a + b == y]` not produce the expected result?

Comment: @PGFTricks The goal of `Simplify` is to minimize its `ComplexityFunction` the default one is similar to [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html) and `a^10 + b^10` is pretty darn simple as far as it is concerned. You can search `ComplexityFunction` on this site for examples with adding penalty to expressions you don't want when simplifying.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple approach is the following :

```
el[n_] := Eliminate[ {r == (A + B)^n - A^n - B^n , x == A + B , y == A*B}, {A,B}]//First

Expand[Array[el, 10]] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 4):

An approach:

```
pol[n_] := Expand[(a + b)^n - a^n - b^n]
sol = Solve[{a + b == x, a b == y}, {a, b}][[1]];
fun[n_] := Expand@Simplify[pol[n] /. sol]
```

Tabulating:

```
Table[{(a + b)^j - a^j - b^j, fun[j]}, {j, 2, 10}] // Grid
```

[image]