# Introducing new variables implicitly

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a calculation

```
expr111 = cs[giso, xiso, 1, 1, 1]
```

that gives the result

> ```
> -((k x)/(2 (1 + 1/4 k (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))))
> ```

I also have two other expressions:

```
fx = -((k rho^2 x)/(1 + 1/4 k (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^3)
ff = rho^2/(1 + 1/4 k (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^2
```

Pretty obviously `expr111 == fx/(2 ff)`. How do I get *Mathematica* to make this substitution?

Comment: Related: [Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions)

Comment: Are you asking, given your definitions, can you get _Mathematica_ to give `fx/ff/2` when you evaluate `exp111`? That's 180 degrees out of phase with _Mathematica_ normal evaluation rules.

Comment: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33457/how-to-replace-every-possible-ab-and-ab-in-expansion-of-ab10-a10/33460#33460) is also very relevant. It works here but you need to transform your fractions to polynomials first (assuming your denominators are non-zero)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it makes no sense when considered in the context of _Mathematica_'s evaluation rules.

Comment: @m_goldberg I was imagining a result like `Hold[fx/(2 ff)]`