# Replace sum x+y+z in expressions like 2x+3y+z

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

Related threads [replacing-a-sum-of-expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56975/replacing-a-sum-of-expressions) and [Replace a sum of squared variables by a new squared variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49244/replace-a-sum-of-squared-variables-by-a-new-variable-squared)

Given the identity $x+y+z=p$ I'd like to simplify the generic expression

$$kx+ly+mz$$

where $k$, $l$, $m$ are positive integer coefficients, but ultimately this shouldn't matter.

The naive ansatz would be to use the rule

```
HoldPattern[Plus[x,y,z]]->p
```

This works fine when $k=1$, $l=1$, and $m=1$ but fails in all other cases. Now the accepted answer in the first linked post, states that you need to define all the rules manually. But this gives this massive object, which leads to $2^c$ possibilities, where $c$ is the number of coefficients.

```
  HoldPattern[Plus[x, y, z]] -> p,
  HoldPattern[Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, x], y, z]] :> 
   Plus[Times[a - 1, x], y, z, p],
  HoldPattern[Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, y], x, z]] :> 
   Plus[Times[a - 1, y], x, z, p],
  HoldPattern[Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, z], x, y]] :> 
   Plus[Times[a - 1, z], x, y, p],
  HoldPattern[Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, x], Times[b_?IntegerQ, y], z]] :>
    Plus[Times[a - Min[a, b], x], Times[b - Min[a, b], y], z, p],
  HoldPattern[Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, x], Times[b_?IntegerQ, z], y]] :>
    Plus[Times[a - Min[a, b], x], Times[b - Min[a, b], z], y, p],
  HoldPattern[Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, y], Times[b_?IntegerQ, z], x]] :>
    Plus[Times[a - Min[a, b], y], Times[b - Min[a, b], z], x, p],
  HoldPattern[
    Plus[Times[a_?IntegerQ, x], Times[b_?IntegerQ, y], 
     Times[c_?IntegerQ, z]]] :> 
   Plus[Times[a - Min[a, b, c], x], Times[b - Min[a, b, c], y], 
    Times[c - Min[a, b, c], z], Times[Min[a, b, c], p]]
  }
```

It should be obvious, that

1. There is a lot of repetition in this code and as a consequence
2. This generalizes very badly, due to the exponential scaling of the possibilities

Example expected results:

1. $5x+2y+3z=3x+z+2p$
2. $3x+2y$ should remained unchanged (optionally)
3. $x+2y+z=p+y$

**What is the general way to apply the above identity to any expression?**

Additional requirement (edited): $p$ should be able to be a more complicated expression, not necessarily atomic.

Comment: maybe `Eliminate[{ss == 5 x + 2 y + 3 z, p == x + y + z}, y]`?

Comment: Is there a requirement that all of the coefficients (except for $p$?) should be positive?

Comment: For more complex expression, look at PolynomialReduce

Comment: @CarlWoll, yes they are all positive.

Comment: Why not `z -> p-x-y`?

Comment: @Eric Towers: because that would make the expression more complicated, if it was only `z`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build another kind of rule

```
rule = a_. x + b_. y + c_. z :> (((a - min) x + (b - min) y + 
                               (c - min) z + min p) /. {min -> Min[a, b, c]})
```

Then

```
(5x+2y+3z /.rule) == 2p+3x+z
(3x+2y /.rule) == 3x + 2y
```

Comment: This only works if a, b AND c are not equal to 1.

Comment: You're right---I added the `.` at the end of `a_.`, `b_.` and `c_.` to match the default in times, now it includes 1.

Comment: That is awesome, I didn't know about it. Where can I find it in the documentation?

Comment: It's under `ref/Default` in the docs.  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html

Comment: The `Default` of `Times` is 1---the multiplicative identity.  Similarly, the default of `Plus` is 0.

Comment: When some of the coefficients are negative this may not give the desired result. I recommend that you change `{min -> Min[a, b, c]})` to `{min -> SortBy[{a, b, c}, Abs][[1]]}`

Comment: I added a condition to this that all coefficients are positive, but interesting point, @Bob Hanlon

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`PolynomialReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce) for this:

```
reduce[e_, p_Symbol->r_, v_List] := Module[{min},
    min = First @ Ordering[Coefficient[e,#]&/@v];
    Replace[
        PolynomialReduce[e, r, v[[min]]],
        {{n_}, s_} :> s + n p
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
reduce[3x + 2y + 5z, p -> x + y + z, {x, y, z}]
reduce[3x + 2y, p -> x + y + z, {x, y, z}]
```

> 2 p + x + 3 z

> 3 x + 2 y

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

repl[expr_, vars : _List : {z, y, x}, p : _Symbol : p] :=
 SortBy[expr /.
     (Solve[Total[vars] == p, #][[1]] & /@ vars) // Simplify,
   LeafCount][[1]]

5 x + 2 y + 3 z // repl

(* 2 p + 3 x + z *)

3 x + 2 y // repl

(* 3 x + 2 y *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Module[{$v}, $v /. Solve[Eliminate[{$v == #, #2}, #3], $v][[1]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f0[a x + b y + c z, p == x + y + z, y] // Simplify
```

> ```
> a x + b (p - x - z) + c z
> ```

```
f0[5 x + 2 y + 3 z, p == x + y + z, y]
```

> ```
> 2 p + 3 x + z
> ```

```
f0[5 x + 2 y + 3 z, p == x + y + z, z]
```

> ```
> 3 p + 2 x - y
> ```

```
f0[ 3 x + 2 y, p == x + y + z, z]
```

> ```
> 3 x + 2 y
> ```

```
f0[ x + 2 y + z, p == x + y + z, z]
```

> ```
> p + y
> ```

```
f0[ x + 2 y + z, p == x + y + z, y]
```

> ```
> 2 p - x - z
> ```

Comment: Something looks wrong with signs. For example, should the first result have `-c*z` as opposed to `c*z`?

Comment: By the way, `eliminate` is not the best maintained of functions. `PolynomialReduce` is now the recommended way to go about these things. But if you really want to live on the wild side, I'd say go with `AlgebraicRules`. Since it is no longer documented I'll show it in all its glory: `replaceBy[p1_, p2_, vars_] := 
 p1 /. AlgebraicRules[p2, 
   Join[vars, Complement[Variables[{p1, p2} /. Equal -> List], vars]]]` (I was forgetting just how much I dislike this function.)

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for both pointers. (Updated with a fix for the sign issue.)