# Solution of a System of Equations Using `Solve`

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, error-tracking

**Part 1**

I am trying to solve a simple system of equations as follows

```
Solve[{A x^B == f, A y^B == g}, {A, B}]
```

But I just get the error

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

I also tried

```
Reduce[{A x^B == f, A y^B == g}, {A, B}]
```

to no avail as it lead to an **endless evaluation**!

I know that in such cases

1- It is a matter of assumptions or conditions that may have not been given to the solver in order to find the solution!

2- Or simply, `Solve` doesn't know how to solve the equation symbolically due to complexity.

However, I couldn't find any useful assumptions to pass to Mathematica or any complexity. Also, I got excited when I saw that Maple just solved it without any assumptions needed as the following picture shows.

So, what is going on here? :)

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

---

**Part 2**

I made some progress that is indicated in my answer below. So, please read it before looking to the questions of this part.

The following questions still remained unanswered to me!

1- Why the command

```
 Reduce[{A x^B == f, A y^B == g}, {A, B}]
```

does not work here?

2- Why I just cannot get the solution in *Real* domain by the following command?

```
 Solve[{A x^B == f, A y^B == g}, {A, B},Reals,MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Trying to plug in some values indicates the Maple solution isn't correct.

Comment: @Feyre: It seems right to me as I obtained the same result of Maple by hand unless there may be fundamental error! :)

Comment: The numbers I tried did not fulfil reduce constraints as provided by @halirutan

Comment: Why does this have a [tag:bugs] tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that that the key feature is to use the `MaxExtraConditions` option for the `Solve` command.

In elaborate answer of *Artes* in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve?lq=1), a very very nice presentation is referred. It is entitled as [**Getting the Most from Algebraic Solvers in Mathematica**](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/videos.html) by **Adam Strzeboński**. You can download the *.cdf* file of the presentation which is really helpful. Slide $10$ to $12$ are the ones that exactly discuss this issue.

I think beginners like me will find the answer of the following questions in that representation

1- What is the difference between `Reduce` and `Solve` command?
2- What are generic and complete solutions?
3- What are parameters and variables?
4- Why `Solve` and `Reduce` command do not accept assumptions on the parameters?

Finally, with the help of the presentation, I found that the command

```
Solve[{A x^B == f, A y^B == g}, {A, B},MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]
```

will give the result.

[image]

Also you can just take the Real domain solution by

```
 Normal[Solve[{A x^B == f, A y^B == g}, {A, B}, MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]] /. {C[1] -> 0}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, very good find!  I find this option quite counterintuitive.  When setting it to `Infinity` or a number, we get no answer.  But setting it to `All` or `Automatic` does give an answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks. :) But Still I didn't get satisfied as I don't know the answer of questions in **Part 2**. Can you kindly think about them and let me know if you got anything. :)

Comment: I don't know. Maybe Wolfram will find it useful if you send these examples to them, showing Solve with MaxExtraConditions -> 0, 1, Infinity, All, Automatic and Reduce.  Maybe there's a good explanation, maybe something is going wrong ... either way it couldn't hurt to show them the examples.  Perhaps there will be a way to improve things in the future.

Comment: @Szabolcs: And how can I send them this example? Is there a well known  e-mail which receives such examples? :)

Comment: support(AT)wolfram(DOT)com is what you should try.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
eq = Eliminate[{A*ra^B == fa, A*rb^B == fb}, A]
Solve[eq, B]

(* {{B->-(Log[fb/fa]/(Log[ra]-Log[rb]))}} *)
```

and as you repeat this or do it by hand, please note that there are certain restrictions on the values. If you want to know what Maple did not tell you, try this

```
Reduce[eq, B]
```

and look at the conditions that need to be fulfilled

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @H.R. There is much to say, see e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)

Comment: @Artes: Thanks for the valuable link. I read your elaborate answer there. But in this case neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` seems to work! :)

Comment: @H.R. These both functions work too however one has to input properly right restrictions for variables. `Solve` can also eliminate variables, e.g. [Am I missing anything? Solving Equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26147/am-i-missing-anything-solving-equations/26148#26148)

Comment: @Artes: What can I do get some answer from Mathematica? Can you kindly write an answer including the right restriction for variables such that it leads to the answer by Maple. :)

Comment: @halirutan: A weird thing is that why `Reduce[expr,vars]` does not work on my original equation without eliminating $A$?  Also, Solve[expr,vars,elims] does not work too!